# Python logger double output

Tags: python, logging

I'm simply trying to have a python logger with a specific format that outputs log messages only to the console. I've tried many different things but I keep getting 2 lines of console output per log call.

Here is my code:

```
    logger = logging.getLogger('my_logger')
    logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)

    # Create console handler
    stream_handler = logging.StreamHandler()
    formatter = logging.Formatter('%(levelname)s - %(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(message)s')
    stream_handler.setFormatter(formatter)
    logger.addHandler(stream_handler)
    logger.info('TEST LOG info')
```

With output:

```
INFO - 2017-08-21 14:30:00,751 - my_logger - TEST LOG info
INFO:my_logger:TEST LOG info
```

I did exactly this and it didn't work: [Disable output of root logger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24750523/disable-output-of-root-logger)

Any idea what is going on? I don't care whether I use the root logger or not, I just want one line

Comment: The code you posted does what you want, if I run it I get just ONE log line. Make sure you're looking at the right output?  Or, you're initializing the logger somewhere else in your code as well.

Comment: Agreed with @IrmendeJong. I tested code, only one-line output.

Answer (score 0):

The above code actually should be working correctly. Although my script was very lean, it was importing a non-system library which, somewhere down the line, had some logging configured which was affecting my output.